# Creating an array of List<LatLng>

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating a routing system and sometimes i'll get 2 or more possible routes. How can I create an array or list of List?

Basically i want to generate one List per route and be able to access them like so:

```
List<LatLng> list[0] //for route 1
List<LatLng> list[1] //for route 2
List<LatLng> list[2] //for route 3
```

etc..

How do i create something like this? For now i can only get one place all the LatLng points of all the routes in one list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < itinerariesLength; i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = itineraries.getJSONObject(i);
    /*--------- legs -----------*/
    JSONArray legsArray = jsonChildNode.getJSONArray("legs");
    for(int j = 0; j < legsArray.length(); j++) {
        List<LatLng> list = util.decodePoly(points);
     }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Used this to store the list of LatLng points.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<List<LatLng>>> parentList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<List<LatLng>>>();
ArrayList<List<LatLng>> childList = new ArrayList<List<LatLng>>();
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an ArrayList inside the ArrayList?(We can call it 2 dimensional ArrayList).

Eg:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> parentList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>();
        ArrayList<LatLng> childList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        childList.add("one");// first route tp place1
        parentList.add(new ArrayList<LatLng> (childList));// all routs to place1

     childList = new ArrayList<LatLng>(); // new routs
childList.add("two"); // first route tp place2
childList.add("three"); //second route tp place2
parentList.add(new ArrayList<LatLng> (childList)); // all routs to place2


ArrayList<LatLng> result=parentList.get(0); // get all routs to place1
System.out.println(result.get(0));// get first rout to place1
```

Comment: But instead of <String> i'll use LatLng?

Comment: See my updated answer. You can use any object inside your ArrayList.